# Can I silence ticker feeds in a chat room?

Tags: support, chat, feed

A chat room can have feeds, either posted as regular messages, or appearing as an overlay at the top of the window (“into an extra area of the screen”) — ticker style. When the feed appears in messages, I can [mute it by clicking on the feed user's avatar next to one of its messages and selecting “ignore this user”](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#mute). What about when the feed is showing up as an overlay? How do I make the overlay never appear to me?

Comment: I'm sure this could easily be done with a userscript or a user stylesheet, but I can't help you... If I return to chat I'll probably never be able to leave, hahaha

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can hide them on your browser using a user stylesheet.  Install [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/), and then create a new user style.

In Firefox, paste the following into it:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("chat.stackexchange.com"), domain("chat.stackoverflow.com"), domain("chat.meta.stackexchange.com") {
    /* Hide the ticker. */
    div#feed-ticker {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

In Chrome, click “Manage installed styles” then “Write new style”, enter the code below:

```
div#feed-ticker {
    display:none !important;
}
```

then click “Specify” next to “Applies to”, select “URLs on the domain” in the drop-down box, enter `chat.stackexchange.com` in the text box and click “Add”; repeat with `chat.stackoverflow.com` and `chat.meta.stackexchange.com`. Finally, enter a name on the left panel, tick “Enabled” and click “Save”.

Comment: This is rather hacky. There shouldn't be a need to do custom styles and such.

Comment: @ThomasOwens True, but this addresses the question's 'how to hide these for me?'  If you want a new feature added to SE, then this needs to be [tag:feature-request] instead of [tag:support].

Comment: Thanks for fishing this one for me. It seems to work under Chrome 25.

Answer (score 4):

Steps to mute "ticker" feeds:

1. Open the room's "feeds" tab.
2. Find the ticker feed, and click "edit"
3. Check the "like regular messages" radio button

   [image: regular messages]
4. Click "save changes"
5. Return to the room and ignore whatever user is associated with the feed.

Yes, this will also change the style for everyone else using the room. You can take this opportunity to inform them of the many advantages that regular message posts provide.

Comment: I don't really like this. The options are to have all users have an annoying overlay or have messages injected into the chat? There should be a middle ground.

Comment: The middle ground is to turn off all feeds and get yourself a real RSS reader.

Comment: Are you seriously encouraging us to start an edit war on the feeds style?

Comment: Naw, you should have a calm discussion regarding the feeds style that naturally arrives at the conclusion that tickers are annoying and opts to avoid them, @Gilles.

Comment: @Shog9 If the world works that way, the SE devs would have come to that conclusion and removed the feature (if not refrained from putting it in altogether).