# Allow us to turn off the newsfeed on the top-left corner

Tags: feature-request, chat, design, notifications

It is possible for a chatroom to have an RSS feed displayed as an overlay in the top left corner. You can click “dismiss” to get rid of the messages already displayed but there is no way for the user to turn off the feed completely.

For me as a user, any kind of asynchronous overlay/interface change is extremely annoying as it grabs my focus from whatever I'm reading. That makes concentrated reading/writing very difficult. This also applies to the notifications on the inbox and the “new answers” bar that pops up asynchronously. Being concentrated is an important prerequisite for writing good answers and comments.

Please give me the ability to completely turn off the RSS overlay without any notifications remaining.

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115224/can-i-silence-ticker-feeds-in-a-chat-room